# Issue on Using jQuery load function

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ajaxq

can you please take a look at this ajax load() function [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/dS6cf/) and let me know why I am not able to load data from the URL into the divs

Here is the code I am using:

```
<div id="result"></div>
<div id="page"></div>

$('#result').load('ajax/http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/index.html .mu-m');
$('#page').load('ajax/http://www.fifa.com/worldcup/index.html');
```

but I am getting this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (NOT FOUND)

Comment: That is a cross site request... You really are not supposed to import pages from others sites, which is why they have a Same Origin Policy!

Answer (score 0):

.load() is only working on the current domain, see [Same-Origin-Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).
It only works if you have control over the other site.